# Angular $http set cookie on each request after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm having troubles with $http calls in AngularJS. I've created the following services

```
    crApp.service('authService', function ($http) {

    var urlBase = 'http://192.168.xx.xx:8081';

    // POST api/login/
    this.login = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post(urlBase + "/api/login", credentials);
    };

  // POST api/logout/
  this.logout = function () {
    return $http.post(urlBase + "/api/logout/", "");
  };

}); //end service

crApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

  var urlBase = 'http://192.168.xx.xx:8081';

  // POST api/query/
  this.pull = function (query) {
    return $http.post(urlBase + "/api/query", query);
  };
```

From the controller I call the login method:

```
$scope.login = function(){
    authService.login(credentials)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("RESULT LOGIN: " + data );
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        });
};
```

So far so good and I receive a response where a cookie is set: 
[image]

After succesfull login I call the following method:

```
var locations = { query: "from location select uid, name, description, address, phone", dataFormat: "verbose" };
$scope.getLocations = function() {
    dataService.pull(portals)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log("RESULT QUERY: " + data)
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Query niet gelukt!");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        });
};
```

Result:

[image]

So cookie is not set in the headers.
I'm using AngularJS 1.3.15 and calls are made to a remote server on a different domain, but it does work in the REST Client tool in WebStorm (Jetbrains). So it must be something i'm missing in Angular!??

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set `withCredentials = true` in the `$http` config to allow cookies to be set on CORS requests. [This article explains more about cookies and CORS](https://quickleft.com/blog/cookies-with-my-cors/).

In your app config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(['$httpProvider'){
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);
```

You can read about this option in the [`$http` provider documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: You need `withCredentials` on the client side, but you also need to set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the server side? If not it will not work. If you see towards the end of the article I linked to, you will see the requirements of the server.

Comment: My colleague who manage the code of the server-side is pretty sure everything is set correct on the server. Other options?

Comment: @MarlonVanDerLaan That's how it works, if it's setup as per that guide with what you have posted it will work. I would verify "pretty sure" because that's a critical part, it is a show stopper there. That header is missing in your above screenshot for the response.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've set withCredentials = true and now a CORS message appears telling the wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot be used. I do see the cookie in the request and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true in the reponse header. So if I understand correct it should be fixed to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the server to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000   ??

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.25.11:8081/api/query. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @MarlonVanDerLaan ah yes I forgot about that rule. The way you can get around that is to have your server match return the origin server name instead of the `*` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Once that is set it looks like you will have it working. So it would need to be `localhost` there

Comment: Just checked and the value should be the full host name with the url scheme. `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: They changed it and now response is ---Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000--- .I'm now getting ---XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.25.11:8081/api/query/. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials---. Grrr... any ideas?

Comment: @MarlonVanDerLaan Perhaps try removing the port number from the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so it is just `http://localhost` You are close I promise, and double check `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is definitely still being set. It wouldn't hurt to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *` as well.

Comment: Ok, they will double check the header. Only `http://localhost` doesn't work. In the meantime i've created some `$.ajax` calls in JQuery resulting in the same issue. This will rule out a problem in Angular.

Comment: At the end they changed some things on the server-side and as you mentioned earlier `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` did the trick. IT WORKS!

Comment: @MarlonVanDerLaan That's great. Good luck with your project.